# NLM Problem: 1 question, 2 equally convincing solutions!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, constrained-dynamics

[image]

**Question:** Two blocks initially at rest are kept in contact as shown in the figure. A force F is applied on the left block. The blocks are of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$. Find the acceleration of the blocks. All surfaces are smooth.

**Attempt at Solution:**
$m_2$ is chosen as reference frame and FBD is drawn as shown above. We get the following equations:

From $m_1$ by choosing axes along and perpendicular to acceleration of $m_1$ w.r.t $m_2$ ($a'$):

$$
m_1 a' + m_1 a \cos{\theta} + m_1 g \sin{\theta} = N_1 \sin{\theta} + F \cos{\theta}\\
N+N_1 \cos{\theta} + m_1 a \sin{\theta} = m_1 g \cos{\theta} + F \sin{\theta}
$$

From $m_2$ by choosing horizontal and vertical axes:
$$
N_2 = N \cos{\theta} + m_2 g\\
m_2 a = N \sin{\theta}
$$

Finally, only one of $N_1$ and $a'$ can be non-zero, since $a'\neq 0\Leftrightarrow$ contact with ground is lost$\Leftrightarrow N_1=0$ and vice-versa.

Choosing $N_1=0$ gives:
$$
a=\frac{m_1 g\cos{\theta} +F\sin{\theta}}{m_1 \sin{\theta}+m_2\csc{\theta}}
$$

$$
N=\frac{m_1 m_2 g\cot{\theta}+m_2 F}{m_1 \sin{\theta}+m_2\csc{\theta}}
$$

$$
N_2 =\frac{m_1 m_2 g\cos{\theta}\cot{\theta}+m_2 F\cos{\theta}+m_1 m_2 g\sin{\theta}+{m_2}^2 g\csc{\theta}}{m_1\sin{\theta}+m_2\csc{\theta}}
$$

Choosing $a'=0$ gives:
$$
a=\frac{F}{m_1 +m_2}
$$

$$
N=\frac{m_2 F\csc{\theta}}{m_1 +m_2}
$$

$$
N_2 =\frac{m_2 F\cot{\theta}+m_1 m_2 g+{m_2}^2 g}{m_1 +m_2}
$$

**Problem:** Both of the two results are possible. Which one will be actually observed? And why?

Comment: The moment that the first block is raised, $N_1$ drops to zero.  So just take $N_1=0$ and the rest is doable assuming $a'\neq0$.  Otherwise, $a'=0$, then you can solve for everything else.

Comment: @user256872 yeah, but which how to know which one to assume? Both are equivalently correct...

Comment: If $F$ is low enough, then the normal forces will simply readjust such that $a'=0$.  If $F$ (which increases $N_2$ thereby decreasing $N_1$) is such that $N_1$ drops to zero, then $a'>0$ and $N_1$ remains nul.

Comment: What, specifically, is enough?

Comment: If you make/don't make N1 drop to zero

Comment: I only have access to the change value of F. What limiting F should I apply to make N_1 drop to 0?

Comment: Assume N1 is zero and solve for F.  The logic is that as you increase F, N2 will increase and N1 will decrease (but contact with ground is maintained).  However, if N2 increases enough to make N1 zero (to find that value, set N1=0), contact with the ground will be lost.